# Is it possible in Facebook Graph API to retrieve ads from feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm thinking about to create a Facebook app, that is scraping ads from my news feed.
I didn't find mentions about distinguishing ads from regular post in feeds.

Can I use Facebook Graph Api to retrieve ads from feed using request /me/feed?

Or is there another way to collect ads in my feed using Graph API?

Comment: No, you can not get those via API.

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase the question: would ads be shown in the response from Graph API in any form?

Comment: no there is not.